# アルファベータ法を書いたつもりですが正常に動作しません。

Tags: python

ミニマックスからアルファベータに修正しました。枝刈りが行われるだけで結果は同じはずですが、異なる結果となってしまいました‌​。符号の入れ替え等を試してみたのですが、‌​動作はするが結果が違うという状況です。カットの判断が違うのか、アルファベータ値の作り方・伝搬方法に問題があるかと思われますが、理由が不明です。

```
def alpha_beta(boad,p,pp,turn,kifu,depth,a,b): #アルファベータ再帰処理

    #カウンタ
    if depth == 0:

        #末端
        kekka = hyouka1(boad,pp)
        return 0,kekka,a,b

    #行き
    can = []
    hyouka = []
    depth = depth - 1
    can = can_put(boad,p)
    if can == []:
        p = -p
        can = can_put(boad,p)
        if can ==[]:
            kekka = hyouka1(boad,p)
            return 0,kekka
        print(turn,p,can)
        print("kita--------------------!")
    for da in can:
        boad,p,turn,kifu,result = put_stone(boad,da,p,turn,kifu)
        turn += 1
        p = -p
        #再帰
        kari,kekka,a,b = alpha_beta(boad,p,pp,turn,kifu,depth,a,b)
        #帰り
        hyouka.append([da,kekka])
        boad,p,turn,kifu = reverse1(boad,p,turn,kifu)
        #もしαβ値を超えたらループを抜ける
        if p == -pp and kekka <= a:
            print("アルファカット")
            break
        if p == -pp and kekka >a:
            a = kekka
            print(a,b)
        if p == pp and kekka >= b:
            print("ベータカット")
            break
        if p == pp and kekka < b:
            b = kekka
            print(a,b)

    if pp == p:
        hyouka = sorted(hyouka, key=lambda hyouka: hyouka[1],reverse=True)
    else:
        hyouka = sorted(hyouka, key=lambda hyouka: hyouka[1],reverse=False)
    da = hyouka[0][0]
    kekka = hyouka[0][1]

    return da,kekka,a,b
```

Comment: "動作しません"では、このコードで結果がどうなったのか分かりません。何処まで実行され、どのように動作しないのか具体的に記載できますでしょうか？また、自身での調査内容も記載するとより良いです

Comment: ミニマックスからアルファベータに修正しました。枝刈りが行われるだけで結果は同じはずですが、異なる結果となってしまいました。符号の入れ替え等を試してみたのですが、動作はするが結果が違うという状況です。

Comment: その旨をコメントではなく、質問文を編集して記載してください。また、出力や結果等があるのであれば合わせて記載するといいかと思います